# multiply functions in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve following functions

```
k=2;
G(1)=292000.0;
G(2)=262000.0;
Ld(1)=0.00396;
Ld(2)=0.0344;
deps=10;
aa=3.7;
ms=0.0;

 for i=1:k
    ms=@(x) ms+(G(i)/Ld(i))*exp(-x./Ld(i))

 end

f=@(x) (exp(x.*2*deps)-exp(-x.*deps))/((aa-3)+(2*exp(x.*deps)+exp(-2*x.*deps)))
g=@(x) ms(x).*f(x)
g(1);
```

but I receive this error "Undefined function or method 'plus' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'."

hope somebody can help me out..Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As Jonas already pointed out, the problem is that you treat `ms` interchangeably as a numeric value and a function handle, which you can't do.

You actually don't need the for loop to generate the anonymous function `ms`. You can create it in one line using the function [SUM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sum.html) like so:

```
ms = @(x) sum((G./Ld).*exp(-x./Ld));
```

This will give you a final result of `g(1) = 0.0199;`.

Comment: Much better than my solution. +1

Answer (score 1):

The problematic lines are:

```
ms=0.0;

 for i=1:k
    ms=@(x) ms+(G(i)/Ld(i))*exp(-x./Ld(i))

 end
```

Inside the loop, you treat `ms` as both a function handle as well as a number, which won't work.

Although recursive definition of a function handle is most likely not the best way to go, it is - to my surprise - possible. Thus, you can write:

```
ms = @(x)0; %# initialize 'ms' to nothing
for i=1:k
    ms = @(x) ms(x) +(G(i)/Ld(i))*exp(-x./Ld(i));
end
```